# How to secure a REST Api on flask

Tags: rest, api, security, flask

I need to develop a Rest API on my app (Based on Flask)

But I don't really know how I should secure it.

Currently, I have a normal authentication for users who are coming from a browser. (Using the session etc.)

But for the API users, should I ask the username/password at every API request ?
Is it really secured ?
I know than a lot of web API use tokens for API calls, is it a best way ?

And in this case, how to implement it ? (This is not really my field of expertise..)
Thanks a lot

Comment: Have a look here, it would help you. still you can use any package for redis sessions for better performance, it is simply a concept of token based authentications.  https://realpython.com/blog/python/token-based-authentication-with-flask/

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You should use `token based authentication` technique to secure your `API`, the concept is simple once your user signs in, your site should save it somewhere and you send back that token to your user.

For each call to your API, user should send token with every API request and you should validate the encoded toke and either deny or send back the response.

Have a look here: https://realpython.com/blog/python/token-based-authentication-with-flask/

Check this too http://flask-jwt-extended.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

For better performance, you can store your session tokens in a `NOSQL` database like `Redis`.

To support logins with social media sites, you should use `OAuth` which is working in the same way except it send back a couple of more tokens to the client.

Comment: It should be noted that when using JWT you don’t need to store your tokens on the backend at all. Each token contains enough information to determine if it is valid and not tampered with, without needing to store anything on the server.

Comment: I also want to know how we can work with XSS when going to implement security in Flask Restful API?