# How to auth for DB connection without hardcoding and exposing credentials?

Tags: python, sql, database, postgresql, authentication

So, basically, my **python** program is a **client that on launch connects to the database** to obtain a token to proceed to work.

For now my authentication method looks completely lame for me and I am not satisfied:

```
async def create_db_connection():
        while True:
            try:
                conn = await asyncpg.connect(
                    user=C.get_credentials(A.Decrypt(user), "vosPgMa"),
                    password=C.get_credentials(A.Decrypt(password), "vosPgMa"),
                    host=C.get_credentials(A.Decrypt(host), "vosPgMa"),
                    port=C.get_credentials(A.Decrypt(port), "vosPgMa"),
                    database=C.get_credentials(A.Decrypt(database), "vosPgMa")
                )
                return conn
            except Exception as e:
                logging.error(f"\n\tError connecting to the database: {e}")
                await asyncio.sleep(0.7)

# Update last time active
    async def log_off_database(token):
        while True:
            try:
                conn = await B.create_db_connection()
                await conn.execute(
                            'UPDATE "Tokens" SET "Status" = $1, "UsedBy" = $2 WHERE "Token" = $3',
                            'Free', '-', token
                        )
            except Exception as e:
                logging.error(f"Error logging off: {e}")
            finally:
                await B.close_db_connection(conn)
            await asyncio.sleep(9)
```

How should I realize the auth process so:

- My credentials weren't stored in any file memory. (including .env)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Accessing a data base on client side can be a problem, specially when you need to run queries like this.
Depending on what kind of program you are building, it can expose your data base to attacks like SQL Injection or similar.

I would recommend you to build an API or any other kind of interface that runs these connections and queries on server side and only returns the results to client side.

With Python you have some libraries that already do part of this work with security for you, like Fast API and Flask.

Read more at:

[Fast API - Security](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/security/)

[How to secure a REST Api on flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47892413/how-to-secure-a-rest-api-on-flask)